# Issue with firebase emulator UI when run locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Google Firestore and want to setup an emulator for local development. All the installation went successfully. However, when I want to start the emulator with `firebase emulators:start` command, it's not successful with launching the UI. It gives the following error in `ui-debug.log`:

```
Error: Cannot find module '<my path>/--dns-result-order=ipv4first'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1955:46)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1983:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

This error is gone when I run the emulator without UI. Can anyone please tell me what this issue might be?

My node version is: v16.15.0
My npm version is: 8.10.0
My firebase version is: 11.0.0

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Saro , could you please include a reproducible code to further check the error you've encountered.

Comment: Hi @MarcAnthonyB, thanks, by reproducible code, which part exactly would you like to have? Since this is just the beginning before even having a code. When my emulator wants to launch, its UI throws that error and it shuts down everything. It tries to find a module with this name: --dns-result-order=ipv4first. When I disable the UI of emulator, this error disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually, it seems that it was a bug and it all started working when I downgraded firebase to 10.9 from 11.
I took help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313155/firebase-emulator-fails-at-startup-cannot-find-module-dns-result-order-ipv4fir).