# Firebase Emulator fails at startup Cannot find module --dns-result-order=ipv4first

Tags: node.js, firebase

The firebase emulator **11.0.0** is failing to start

```
firebase emulators:start
```

an Exception is thrown when it gets to Emulator UI...

> **i ui:** Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
> **⚠  ui:** Fatal error occurred: Emulator UI has exited with code: 1, stopping all running emulators
> **i   ui:** Stopping Emulator UI
> **⚠  ui**: Error stopping Emulator UI

The stack trace from **ui-debug.log** shows...

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   throw err;
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/hayden/Desktop/parent_app_firebase_cloud_emulator/functions/--dns-result-order=ipv4first'.
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15).
> at Function._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1955:46).
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27).
> at Function.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1983:12).
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }.

Looks like the error has something to do with line 84...

```
Starting Emulator UI with command {"binary":"node","args":["--dns-result-order=ipv4first"
```

Which then throw an error in node as its unable to find a module called **--dns-result-order=ipv4first**

Any ideas on how to startup the local firebase emulator so it runs without failing with this exception?

*Running Node 16 and Firebase 11.0.0*

Comment: only solution I've found is to **revert to Firebase 10.9.2**

Please comment/vote if anyone else has the same issue and I'll post the bug on their repo

Comment: Exactly the same. Downgrading firebase cli from 11 to 10.9.2 does the trick for me. Using node 16

Comment: Execute "npm i firebase-tools@10.9.2" to install the version where this issue is not reproducible

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4566

Comment: You should post the content of those images as copy-pastable text, instead of images. This is likely why the question was closed and left closed in review

Answer (score 7):

This bug still exists but thanks to the
[github link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4566) provided by @Viktor the firebase team have located the issue and provided a temporary work-around...

**Issue source:** standalone Firebase CLI binary

**Solution:** remove the standalone binary & re-install with npm...

Step 1. locate firebase standalone binary..

```
which firebase
```

*prints something like... **/usr/local/bin/firebase***

Step 2. rename or delete this folder...

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/firebase /usr/local/bin/firebase_broken
```

Step 3. reinstall using **npm**

```
 npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Step 4. Good to go! re-run from project folder...

```
firebase emulators:start
```

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading to 10.9.2 fixes the issue for me:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools@10.9.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes downgrading works. On Mac I had to execute following:

```
sudo npm i -g firebase-tools@10.9.2 --force
```